# SQL sum grouped by field with all rows

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, rows

I have this table:

```
id  sale_id  price
-------------------
1     1       100
2     1       200
3     2       50 
4     3       50
```

I want this result:

```
id  sale_id  price  sum(price by sale_id)
------------------------------------------
1     1       100    300
2     1       200    300
3     2       50      50
4     3       50      50
```

I tried this:

```
SELECT id, sale_id, price, 
(SELECT sum(price) FROM sale_lines GROUP BY sale_id) 
FROM sale_lines
```

But get the error that subquery returns different number of rows.
How can I do it?

I want all the rows of sale_lines table selecting all fields and adding the sum(price) grouped by sale_id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *window* function :

```
sum(price) over (partition by sale_id) as sum
```

If you want sub-query then you need to correlate them :

```
SELECT sl.id, sl.sale_id, sl.price, 
       (SELECT sum(sll.price) 
        FROM sale_lines sll 
        WHERE sl.sale_id = sll.sale_id 
        ) 
FROM sale_lines sl;
```

Comment: Which is more efficient? seems over partition would be better? Tank you!

Comment: @slayerbleast. . .  Window function will run faster comparative to Sub-query as it doesn't need to call the table again.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `GROUP BY` in the sub-query, make it a co-related sub-query:

```
SELECT sl1.id, sl1.sale_id, sl1.price, 
       (SELECT sum(sl2.price) FROM sale_lines sl2 where sl2.sale_id = sl.sale_id) as total 
FROM sale_lines sl1
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other approaches, You can use CROSS APPLY and get the sum.

```
SELECT id, sale_id,price, Price_Sum
FROM YourTable AS ot
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT SUM(price) AS Price_Sum
FROM YourTable
WHERE sale_id = ot.sale_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, 
       total_price 
FROM   `sale_lines` AS t1 
       JOIN(SELECT Sum(price) AS total_price, 
                   sale_id 
            FROM   sale_lines 
            GROUP  BY sale_id) AS t2 
         ON t1.sale_id = t2.sale_id
```